# How to include std:list in a (C++) constructors parameter list?

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, stl, rad-studio

I have legacy code written in BorlandC++ using `Tlist` and other Borland specific classes. I'm a total noob on STL.

I can't figure out how to redeclare a constructor that looks like this:

```
MyData (TStringList *fileList)
```

the declaration below gives the error missing ")" ! (Compiled in BorlandC++/embarcadero)

```
MyData (std:list<string> *fileList)
```

What's wrong above? how should it be declared with `std:list`

(I'm aware a lot of code will have to be changed since `TStringList` doesn't have the same methods as `std:list`.)

Comment: why do you want to redeclare the constructor to begin with? They not only have different methods, but they are two different types

Comment: `std::list` is the name of a template; it can't be the type of an argument, because it's not a type. Guessing, from `TStringList`, perhaps you're looking for `MyData(const std::list<std::string>& fileList)`?

Comment: Did you use `#include <list>` in your code properly?

Comment: I worked with the Borland Class Library (pre-STL) back in the day.  What you are attempting to do is both noble, and will be very frustrating.  Especially if you are a total noob on STL.  First thing to do is to read up on standard C++ library, which has taken the STL and continued to evolve it.  I recommend Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language (4th edition) book.

Comment: _@nero_ _"I'm aware a lot of code will have to be changed"_ `TStringList` also has totally different behavior regarding notifications of other components about changes made to the instance. It's probably not such a good idea. to replace that with a `std::list<std::string>`. Also, I'd prefer to use a `std::vector<std::string>`, if you're really sure you can replace that.

Comment: Why is `std:list<string>` with single colon?  It should be `std::list<string>` (double colon).

Comment: Awesome place this is! Thx all.

Comment: @user463035818,because AnsiString,List and StringList arent available in visualC (I suppose)

Comment: @Eljay, thx, I fear a lot of work ahead! :D .@πάντα ῥεῖ Interesting suggestion about using vector, I'll look into that. And yes, single colon was an embarrising mistake :)

Comment: FYI, `TStringList` contains a dynamic array of strings, so it would translate closer to `std::vector<std::string>` than to `std::list<std::string>`, which is a double linked list, not an array. Don't let the names fool you. You need to understand the semantics in order to translate effectively. You might consider writing a custom `TStringList` class that has the same public interface as the Borland class but uses the STL internally. Same with `AnsiString` and other Borland classes. That way, you have less code to translate

Answer (score 2):

[Namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) use the scope resolution operator `::`, not single colon `:`

Both `list` and `string` are in the `std` namespace and are therefore accessed with `::`

This works: `MyData(std::list<std::string> *fileList)`

---

From Thomas Matthews's comment: Passing by reference is preferred over passing by pointer: `MyData(std::list<std::string> &fileList)`

Comment: Also, passing by reference is preferred over passing by pointer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I prefer pass-by-pointer if the actual object is going to be modified. It's not clear when calling the function that the object will be modified if you  use pass-by-reference: `MyData(&fileList)` vs `MyData(fileList)`.

Comment: If you don't want the object to be modified then pass by `const` reference. That should be clear enough.

Comment: they `const ` keyword allows for clear communication that you are not gone touch that object.
Remember reference's cant be null. pointers can be. it safe you allot of null checks if you pass by references